# visit ViewModel in Recycler´s Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, viewmodel

i am stuck in the problem that, i want to visit my ViewModel in a RecyclerView´s Adapter, but i have the Exception:
"Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call"

```
class FoodInSortAdapter( val activity:MainActivity,private val list:List<String>):RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodInSortAdapter.Holder>() {

    val viewModel :FoodViewModel by lazy {
        println("servus")
        ViewModelProvider(activity).get(FoodViewModel::class.java)}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.sortitem, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.sortName.text = list[position]
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val m=list[position]
            viewModel.setQuery(m)
        }
    }
```

anyone know what ´s wrong?

thanks

Comment: While posting your question. Post the code snippet directly. It will be easier for other and you will get faster answer.

Comment: @CodeWithVikas, thanks for advice, just new to here. you mean CodeSample , or BlockQuote?

Comment: either is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you should not initialize viewModel outside of activity or fragment.

I assume you do not create adapter in `onCreate` but during initialization phase. There are two solution for your concern.

1. Initialize vm in activity, and set it in adapter by newly added method `setupViewModel`, called in `onCreate`. That's the better one.

```
class FooActivity : Activity{

  private val viewModel: FoodViewModel by lazy {
        println("servus")
        ViewModelProvider(activity).get(FoodViewModel::class.java)
  }

  private val adapter = FoodInSortAdapter(emptyList())

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        adapter.setupViewModel(viewModel)
  }

}

class FoodInSortAdapter(private val list:List<String>):RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodInSortAdapter.Holder>() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: FoodViewModel

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.sortitem, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.sortName.text = list[position]
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val m=list[position]
            viewModel.setQuery(m)
        }
    }

   fun setupViewModel(vm: FoodViewModel){
      viewModel = vm
   }
}
```

2. Create adapter in `onCreate` method, that should also work for you.

Cheers

Comment: First Use observe method to get the model data and put in to a list and then pass it to a recyclerview.

Comment: @Rabbit wants to pass viewModel to invoke `setQuery`, not just to pass data as a list

Comment: Hi, yes , i want to invoke the setQuery method in VM. which triggers another web - inquiry with this parameter m, (which i click on a recyclerView)

Comment: @JakubPruszyński, sorry i don´t quite understand your first suggestion. it looks cool :) any example :>

Comment: @Rabbit I have updated the post with example based on your question

Comment: @JakubPruszyński, i want to thank you for your solution, it helps me out of the situation, in which i almost want to give up learning Android.

Comment: @JakubPruszyński, but i still want to ask you, what is the standard way  (is there a standard way?) by clicking a recylerview item in adapter to invoke another web-inquiry in vm?, thanks

Comment: @Rabbit I am glad to here that so please mark response as correct. Meanwhile there is no such standard way but please consider that applying design patterns and splinting concerns always leads to better design. In your example the same result you could achieve in at least four ways, the tricky part is to see them and choose the best to your needs. Don't stop pushing yourself :)